# Подскажите решение для ajax загрузки фотографий + захват фото с вебкамеры

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, fileupload, web-camera

Нашел хорошее решение для загрузки фоток с диска:
http://fineuploader.com/demos.html
И решение для захвата фото с вебкамеры и загрузка его на сервер:
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/04/jquery-webcam-photobooth/

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, решение на php + JS, которое умеет делать сразу 2 эти вещи.
Спасибо!

Comment: Мир был бы немного лучше, если бы тут писали исключительно по существу

Comment: И правда, особенно спрашивальщики...... По существу: ваш вопрос (и даже **НЕ ВОПРОС**) оффтоп, так как не соответствует [правилам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) данного ресурса. Соответственно, вам надо их почитать и только после этого задавать **ВОПРОС**, а не просьбу накинуть решений

Comment: Думаю, моя проблема достаточно ясно сформулирована

Comment: Вы написали вопрос, в котором отсутствует....ВОПРОС.......А проблема ваша в том, что вы не хотите прикладывать усилий для решения задачи и желаете, чтобы вам написали код. Если вам нужна помощь, а не готовый код, задавайте конкретные вопросы:  что именно вы делали, что не получилось.. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, да и вообще,есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон

Comment: Попробуйте еще раз перечитать мой вопрос и найти в нем просьбу написать за меня код. Можете попробовать сделать это несколько раз, до полного прозрения... Я спросил у сообщества название готового решения моей задачи, если оно существует в принципе. Да, в этом и был мой вопрос, не более.

Comment: Название: "руки и мозг"

Comment: Рано или поздно каждый разработчик приходит к выводу, что лучше/быстрее/надежнее использовать в работе готовые протестированные и отлаженные решения, там где это возможно, чем изобретать свои велосипеды и тратить дополнительные человекочасы на дебаггинг и поддержку. Хотя, опять же, для этого осознания опыта и рук, очевидно, недостаточно, необходим еще и мозг...

Comment: Велосипеды свои нужны и важны. Ибо нет универсальных средств для всех нужд..... Те, кто копипастит сплошными решениями - называется кодер. Такие ни на что не способны и в случае маленькой задачи - сразу сыпятся.их увольняют и больше не имеют с ними дел..  Разработчик, исходя из именования, - разрабатывает. Компаниям, нужны не тупые макаки кодеры, а разработчики, способные хотя бы элементарно связать некоторые вещи.... Вот у вас есть два готовых решения (рама с цепью и руль с колесом) и вы не можете их связать воедино (собрать велосипед).... Вывод делайте сами..

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Жестковато Вы как-то. У человека сейчас руки опустятся и потеряем еще одного участника. :)